# cycle in C#.NET win form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have C#.NET program and I want to check something every 2 seconds until my form is closed. This cycle doesn't enable with user for other hand when user run my C#.NET form cycle is start until form closed.

For example I want to check internet connection when my form is used. I don't like checking the connection in `form.load;`. I want to check connection is every time.

Comment: They invented a Threaded Timer some time ago (especially for such use-cases). What have you tried?

Comment: I 'm beginner . I don't know a lot C#.Net but I try to use internet connection of user in every time . timer is good . I try to use it . thanks

Comment: Can you give example ... Thanks you so much

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/timers

Comment: Though if you need this every 2 seconds, well what if it takes more than 2 seconds to check?

Comment: ok . 2 second is bad choices . thank you for your answer ...

Comment: If you want to test Internet connection, use notification interfaces like **INetworkListManagerEvents**

Answer (score -1):

this code is worked :

> cycle Timer in winForm  c#.NET

```
 using Timer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer MyTimer = new Timer();
    MyTimer.Interval = (45 * 60 * 1000); // 45 mins
    MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
    MyTimer.Start();
}
private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Check for internet connection or some other work here
    Timer MyTimer = new Timer();
    MyTimer.Interval = (45 * 60 * 1000); // 45 mins
    MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
    MyTimer.Start();
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating and starting a new timer under `MyTimer_Tick`? That's probably going to throw a StackOverflowException eventually.